# Different app titles on home screen and title bar during launch?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-titlebar

The name of my app is too long to fit on the home screen.  But it will easily fit on the bar that shows up during launch.  Can I make the two names differ?  If so, how?

The below is what I have currently, via Xamarin.  The title setting does not appear to do anything.  "Free GraCalc" shows both on the home screen and as the title during launch.

```
  [Activity(Label = "Free GraCalc", MainLauncher = true)]
  public class MainTabActivity : Activity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      this.Title = "Free Graphing Calculator";
      // other stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin, but in Android that can easily be done through the manifest.

Comment: Xamarin has a manifest too -- how do you do it in Android?

Comment: To change the title on the navigation bar you just add android:label="@string/Your_string" in the manifest under each activity that you want to change the title on.

Comment: To change the title of your app for the icon you change the string <string name="app_name">AppName</string> in your strings.xml